# How can I edit an embed that has been sent before?

Tags: cron, discord, discord.js, bots

This is my code and it isnt working, it says that it needs to be in an async function but I dont know where to put the async, also im using cron npm

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const config = require('./config.json')
const cron = require('cron');
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("EMBED TITLE")
.setDescription("EMBED DESCRIPTION")

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)

})

const welchannel = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID") //the id of the channel is going to be sent
const msg =  await welchannel.send(embed)

let sevencron = new cron.CronJob('00 * 7 * * 1', () => {
  const oneembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("EDIT_EMBED_TITLE")
  .setDescription('EDIT_EMBED_DESCRIPTION')
 msg.edit(oneembed)
});

sevencron.start()


client.login(config.token)
```

Comment: You should put that before your `()` in your `ready` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right here:

```
                       |
                       V
client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)

})
```